# Language reverts back to English after changing orientation

Tags: android

When i select a language in portrait mode, it works fine. when i change orientation to landscape and back to portrait mode by default language English gets selected.

I tried this code in android menifest file

android:configChanges="keyboard|Hidden|screenSize|orientation

So can any one suggest me how to achieve the above requirement?
Thanx in advance

Comment: where do you change language? on system preferences?

you should add "locale" on configChanges

Comment: you need to provide some code, but it looks like you're setting the app language somehow from the code, and the orientation change isn't taking that in consideration

Comment: Configuration conf = res.getConfiguration();

conf.locale = locale;

res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);

Comment: at the begining of the app itself it asks to pick a language, so i have used updateConfiguration().

Respected strings are in strings.xml (for other languages too)

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Set your locale here...
    }
```

> in your activity class add above code, when rotation is changed above method is called and locale not remember what you locale set on portrait locale.

Answer (score -1):

Right way is to handle it from your application Object.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Set your locale here...
    }
}
```

Comment: if we change locale from activity it is better because application class fix this lang, but in our setting we given option to user change language thats why its better to handle in activity class

Comment: @Yogesh Rathi come on man, with your solution we must handle onConfigurationChanged method in all Activities, Right?

Comment: no dear you can declare your own activity and extends all activity in your custom activity class

Comment: ex. CutomActivity extends Activity and what ever your app have 100 activity, extends your all activity to CutomActivity class.